# How do I install vim on OSX with Python 3 support?

Tags: macos, vim, python3

In the google searches I've done, the command I should be using is `brew install vim --with-python3`, which succeeds without error, but then `vim --version` reports Python 3 as unavailable.

```
k162:~ asday$ brew install vim --with-python3
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v7.4.2210.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/asday/Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-7.4.2210.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2210/share/man --enable-multibyte --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-cscope --with-compiledby=Homebrew --enable-p
==> make
==> make install prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2210 STRIP=true
  /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2210: 1,732 files, 28.5M, built in 52 seconds
k162:~ asday$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2015 16:22:14)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

And doing `:py3 print("")` within vim returns `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`.

What is it I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to compile vim myself?

Comment: Did you try `brew install vim --without-python --with-python3` (that is, explicitly specify `--without-python` as well).

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work.  I needed to uninstall vim completely and do `brew cleanup`, then `brew install vim --with-python3` worked.

Comment: Have you by any chance figured the solution, @AdamBarnes? For some reason, I'm right now failing to build Homebrew's vim8 `--with-python3`...

Comment: I'd try `brew remove vim` then `brew cleanup`, then try the command listed in my comment from 21/08.  If that doesn't work then I have no idea; I'm fairly convinced mine working now is a fluke - hence not posting my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following works as of 26 May 2017 when a `-python3` version of Vim is already installed via homebrew:

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim --with-python3
```

Comment: this now reports `Warning: vim: this formula has no --with-python3 option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: @Tommy, that's because Python3 is now the default `python` in Homebrew. If you run `brew info vim`, you'll see that there's an option (`--with-python@2`) to use Python2 instead of Python3.

Comment: @Tommy May I further infer that you are looking at this question today because Homebrew recently installed or upgraded `python@2`, perhaps as a dependency, and it's confounding your Vim scripts?

Comment: seeing some of the output (like `brew info vim`) following this install would be useful

Answer (score 10):

> Already get to make it work. vim formula installs vim with python3
>   support only if python --version is version 3. Doesn't matter if brew
>   install python install python version 3 (because it does in another
>   binary: python3)

From: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/8iymh8/vim_in_osx_with_python3_support/dyx1b94/

Here are my steps:

1. `alias python=python3`
2. `brew install vim`
3. at this point, I get `+python3` in the `vim --version` output
4. `unalias python`

Comment: It seems to me that you’re reporting that somebody else got it to succeed.  Do you have first-hand experience with this?  Can you explain what Adam needs to do to get it to work on his system?

Comment: @Scott thanks for the comment. Yes, I tried this before posting the answer. Here are my steps:

1. `alias python=python3`
2. `brew install vim`
3. at this point, I get `+python3` in the `vim --version` output
4. `unalias python`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Please [edit] your answer to include the relevant information.   (You’ll be able to format it better there.)

Comment: I was able to get rid of python (2) support in MacVim using this method. It was causing the dreaded `this vim cannot execute py3 after using python` issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since version [1.6.0](https://brew.sh/2018/04/09/homebrew-1.6.0/) of Homebrew (2018-04-09), the default python version is 3. Thus, if you have a version of vim installed before this change which is compiled with python2, what you need to do now to get vim with python3 is simply:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
$ brew uninstall --force vim
$ brew cleanup
$ brew install vim
$ vim --version | grep python
```

Comment: what's the output of `vim --version | grep python` that we should be expecting here?

Comment: @baxx just to verify that the version is Python 2 before the upgrade, and Python 3 after upgrade

Answer (score 4):

It is because there was an already installed `vim` in your system which is normally found in `/usr/loca/vim`

```
$ which vim
```

You can try `ls /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2210` and take a look what folders are available. In my system, in that directory i have `bin/vim`, so I update my `.zshrc` or similar rc file in your os, update it as

```
alias 'vim'=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2210/bin/vim
```

When you open a new terminal, then

```
which vim
```

It will show the update path. So you can use the python3 inside it.

Comment: I added the alias to my `~/.bash_aliases` instead. I also used `/usr/local/bin/vim` as the alias which is created by homebrew via `brew link vim`

Comment: I installed vim using brew and alias it as said in this answer. But my vim was located in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/vim/9.0.0200/bin/vim`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue today. No matter

```
brew install vim --with-python3
```

or

```
brew install vim --without-python --with-python3
```

So i check Homebrew's logs at `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/vim`, in `01.configure` i found

```
checking Python is 3.0 or better... too old
```

This is because configure can not find python3's path

By adding `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.X.X/bin` (your path may be different) to your `PATH` envoriment and re-run, the vim finally got compiled with `+python3`

Comment: It seems that install vim with brew and python 3 support also requires python to be install with brew and set in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Put the following in you `.zshrc` or anything `.   rc`:

```bsh
if (command -v brew && brew list --formula | grep -c vim ) > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    alias vim="$(brew --prefix vim)/bin/vim"
fi
```

This will resolve to Homebrew's `vim` only when homebrew is installed`

Comment: This works for me. I just install `macvim` and start vim from `$(brew --prefix vim)/bin/bim`. Thanks.

Comment: @VincentHuang it's a bit slower to run `brew --prefix vim` everytime you run Vim because it needs to load brew first. The advantage of making it an alias is that the brew prefix is fetched only once, when defining the alias, and then it's just a fixed path. I'm happy that this helped you ! :D

Answer (score 3):

Another way to install Vim with Python3 support is using `port` from [The MacPorts Project](https://www.macports.org/):

To check how many variants available for VIM and their conflict:

```
port variant vim
```

To install vim with python3 support:

```
sudo port install vim +python37
```

And to uninstall, just:

```
sudo port uninstall vim
```

Comment: Thanks, for me `--with-python3` wasn't working with brew but using ports made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In latest brew, --with-python3 has been deprecated,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509753/install-caffe-on-mac-error-invalid-option-with-python)

try this,

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim -vd protobuf
```

restart the terminal, and do

```
vim --version
```

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2017 this works.

If you have previously installed vim with homebrew, uninstall it first

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
```

Then

```
brew install vim --without-python --with-python3
```

Comment: `vim: this formula has no --with-python3`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `vim` is still resolving to the Apple-installed version. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313708/apples-vim-always-used-instead-of-homebrew

Comment: You can try `echo $EDITOR` to see if it's set to `vi` (pointing to Apple's `vim`) or `vim`, which is presumably your own.

Answer (score 0):

This variation turned out to be my problem:

I was activating a Python VirtualEnv automatically in .bash_profile/.zshrc before adding certain things (such as homebrew) to my path.

The solution was to put the `source venv/bin/activate` line at the end of .bash_profile, and then run `deactivate` when I launched my terminal to install vim.  At that point, I followed the above answers and ran:

`brew remove vim; brew cleanup; brew install vim`

and everything was good.

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case any fellow tmux users run into this issue. tmux was using the right shell (zsh in my case), but because my .zshrc file didn't specify the vim installation to use, it defaulted to the system one instead of the new version I installed with python3 support (using `brew install vim -vd protobuf` iirc). I noticed this by running `which vim` both inside and outside tmux, which returned different paths. The resolution was to add an alias to my .zshrc file to specify the vim version I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using neovim, then install as you'd normally do:

```
brew install nvim
```

and then install its python support:

```
pip install pynvim --upgrade
```

In order to check whether it worked, go into nvim and run `:checkhealth` - it will show you a red warning if Python is not supported and it will tell you what to do.